# Regex to match `rel` attribute of `img` element which only exists sometimes

Tags: regex, perl

I am facing a problem with a Perl regex. On an `img` element, I want to match the `src` attribute with a value starting with `/file?id`, and with any `class` and `alt` attribute. I want to ignore the `rel` attribute which sometimes exist and sometimes not exist like below:

```
<img rel="lightbox[45451]" src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg">    

<img  src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg">
```

My question is how to handle the optional `rel` attribute.

I am trying this for the `rel` attribute match:

```
(?!\s+(rel)="([^"]+)")
```

It works when there is no `rel` attribute but fails when the `img` has a `rel` attribute.

Comment: [Don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068), use a real [HTML parser](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) instead.

Comment: January: You meant (ii) learning how to *not* regex.

Comment: @Quentin using a regex to match a known, limited subset of HTML/XML can be fine, depending on the desired level of robustness vs. complexity & performance. Aka it's OK to break the rules when you know why and what the consequences are.

Comment: @January: Not really. Using a ready-built parser is almost always quicker and less dirty than using regular expressions. And HTML is a poor target for regular expressions, as evinced by this very question, and will mislead the learner.

Comment: Exactly there are specific cases you will want to use regex but XML/HTML isn't one.

Comment: @January: I wholeheartedly disagree. A regex cannot possibly be *"more durable"* than a parser written for the domain. In particular, the task is so complex that it needs very comprehensive testing, and can never be confirmed as correct. Learning a language by writing code for data it wasn't intended to process cannot be a good way to go. HTML is not a regular language, and you can never write a complete general HTML-processing solution using regular expressions. You may as well advocate writing client-side scripts in Logo.

Comment: @January: No. Using a regular expression to process an irregular language is a *bad idea*. Please don't evangelise your wrong-headedness.

Comment: @January you said it right 15~20 years ago we were at the point of inventing the wheel, today we don't need to invent it, it exists so we can simple deploy the existent wheels instead of going back to a 15~20 years ago process of inventing, testing and finding all the possible issues for it.

Comment: @Borodin. Yeah, whatever, I'm outta here.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial to do using a proper HTML parser. This program demonstrates using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) and the `look_down` method.

It is searching for all elements with:

- A tag name of 'img'
- A `src` attribute that matches the regex qr|^/file\?id=|
- A `class` attribute that matches the null regex (i.e. a class attribute with any value)
- An `alt` attribute that matches the null regex

You don't say what you want to *do* with the elements once you've found them. This code just uses `as_HTML` to display them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file(\*DATA);
my @images = $html->look_down(
  _tag => 'img',
  src => qr|^/file\?id=|,
  class => qr//,
  alt => qr//
);
print $_->as_HTML, "\n" for @images;

__DATA__
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page title</title>
  </head.
  <body>
    <img rel="lightbox[45451]" src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg">    
    <img  src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg">
    <img  src="/file" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg"> /* mismatch id="" */
    <img  src="/file?id=13166" alt="myimagess.jpg">        /* no class="" */
    <img  src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img">            /* no alt="" */
  </body>
</html>
```

**output**

```
<img alt="myimagess.jpg" class="bbc_img" rel="lightbox[45451]" src="/file?id=13166" />
<img alt="myimagess.jpg" class="bbc_img" src="/file?id=13166" />
```

Answer (score 2):

[Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) wins!

```
use Web::Query 'wq';
my $html = <<'';
<html>
<img rel="lightbox[45451]" src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess1.jpg">
<img class="bbc_img" src="/file?id=13167" alt="myimagess2.jpg">
<img src="/file?id=13168" class="bbc_img" >
<img src="/file?id=13169" alt="myimagess3.jpg">
<img  src="/foo" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg4">

print for wq($html)->find('img[src^="/file?id="][class][alt]')->attr('src');
__END__
/file?id=13166
/file?id=13167
```

Learn from this: XPath is more powerful than CSS selectors, but CSS selectors are shorter.

Comment: agreed, although I am waiting for the obligatory XSH2 solution to crown the winner ;--)

Answer (score 1):

A proper way to do this, using [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath). This will ignore `rel` and any other attribute, as well as not depend on the order of attributes in the tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use Test::More tests => 1;

my $root= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( do { local undef $/; <DATA> });

# this is the important part 
my @imgs= $root->findnodes( '//img[starts-with( @src,"/file?id=") and @class and @alt]');

# checks the results
my $hits= join ' ', map { "H:" . src_id( $_->{src}) } @imgs;
is( $hits, 'H:13166 H:13167', "one test");

# shows how to access the attributes
foreach my $img (@imgs)
  { warn "hit: src= $img->{src} - class=$img->{class} - alt: $img->{alt} - id= ", src_id( $img->{src}), "\n"; }

exit; 

sub src_id
  { my( $src)= @_;
    return $src=~  m{/file\?id=(.+)$} ? $1 : 'no id'; 
  }

__DATA__
<html>
  <head><title>Test HTML</title></head.
  <body>
    <img rel="lightbox[45451]" src="/file?id=13166" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess1.jpg">
    <img class="bbc_img" src="/file?id=13167" alt="myimagess2.jpg">
    <img src="/file?id=13168" class="bbc_img" >
    <img src="/file?id=13169" alt="myimagess3.jpg">
    <img  src="/foo" class="bbc_img" alt="myimagess.jpg4">
  </body>
</html>
```